# How count an Arabic substring with substr_count on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, substring, arabic, substr

I'm trying to count a set of arabic substrings stored in a MySQL DB text set on utf8mb4_bin. The 
php file is also set to utf-8 so words actually are displayed correctly.

I can count any subtring so far for any language except arabic (Japanese, Korean, Thai, English, etc...are working fine) But can't get Arabic to work.

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES utf8mb4");
    $query_main = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT word FROM lang_dicc WHERE lang = ".$lang." ORDER BY value;");

    while ($query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_main) ){
        $vector_1[$i] = mb_substr_count( $text, $query["word"]);
    }
```

I already set php.ini file to:
mbstring.func_overload = 7

I'm confused cause strpos() actually CAN find the substring...

I'm wildly guessing is the writing backwards thing? I'm completely lost with this. Specially cause I cannot read the words I have no idea if they are backwards or not.

I would appreciate any insight on this.

-thanks

Comment: Arabic is RightToLeft Language, but i think is has to thing todo with your problem :\

Answer (score 1):

I have been through a similar problem with the arabic language recently and I can see it is not explained anywhere, according to my short research, therefore, I'll leave this answer here regardless that the answer was asked long ago.

**The short answer**
We can use

```
iconv_strlen("نص بالعربي");
```

The explanition why normal substr/strlen don't work, is because each arabic letter is counted as two bytes. For instance,

```
print("نص بالعربي" . ": " . strlen("نص بالعربي"));
print("نص بالعربي" . ": " . iconv_strlen("نص بالعربي"));
```

Those will output
نص بالعربي: 19
نص بالعربي: 10

The normal strlen counted the bytes. The string has 9 arabic character and one white space. 9*2 + 1*1 = 19.

The second one outputed 10, because it counted the characters rather than the bytes.

**Odd behaviour related to substr**
Printing an arabic string works fine. However, printing a letter of the string will result in printing a question-mark.

```
// substr( string, startIndex, Length);
$name = "محمد";
print($name);
print($name[0]);
print(substr($name, 0, 1));
print(substr($name, 0, 2));
```

output:
محمد
�
�
م

Instead of multipling by two or dividing by two when extracting a part of the string, one can use the following method

```
// mb_substr( string, startIndex, Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

use mb_substr_count instead.
you need mbstring extension to be installed

Comment: mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); + mb_substr_count();

seemed to do the trick.

Comment: nope, didn't work...strpos works, but not substr_count